# Java Null Pointer Exception in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get past a null element in an array of String elements in Java. How do I do it. My code looks like this:

```
if(list[pos] != null){
    for(int i = 0; i < list[pos].length(); i++){
        if(list[pos].charAt(i) == 'a' || list[pos].charAt(i) == 'e' || 
           list[pos].charAt(i) == 'i' || list[pos].charAt(i) == 'o' ||
           list[pos].charAt(i) == 'u')
            count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does the `NullPointerException` correspond to?

Comment: You need to check if the list is null.

Comment: I am sorry. It doesn't give a null pointer exception. It's supposed to go through the entire array, but the first element is null, so I was wondering how do you skip past that element

Comment: What are all the values in the list?

Comment: ["some", null, "string", "like", "elements"]

Comment: You aren't iterating over the elements of the list, at least not in what you've shown us. You're only iterating over the contents of list[pos], and you've already protected against null. You need an outer loop incrementing `pos` through the elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that `list[pos]` is `null`, or that `list` itself is `null`. Both cases translate to the same problem: you forgot to instantiate an object somewhere in your code, but it's impossible to determine where without more information.

Comment: If `list[pos]` were null however, the whole if-statement wouldn't be entered.

Comment: Since he's checking for `list[pos]!=null`, I'd bet list is null.

Which line is the exception's call stack reporting as causing the problem?

Comment: Supposes the array looks like this [null, "string", "of", "lines"]. My for loop is supposed to work only on non-null elements. But it doesn't skip to that part. It reads the null element and gives the wrong output

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question you apparently meant to ask:

```
for(pos=0;pos<list.size;++pos)
{
    if(list[pos] != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < list[pos].length(); i++){
            if(list[pos].charAt(i) == 'a' || list[pos].charAt(i) == 'e' || 
               list[pos].charAt(i) == 'i' || list[pos].charAt(i) == 'o' ||
               list[pos].charAt(i) == 'u')
                count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code snippet above:

```
if (list == null) {
    System.out.println("List is null !!");
} else if (list[pos] != null) {
    //ur code here
} else {
    System.out.println("List[pos] is null !!");
}
```

Comment: I only need to skip the null element though. I don't have to print any of that stuff out

Comment: datz for debug purpose; u can avoid it; did u tried d above updates?

Comment: I did. Still no change

Comment: can share with me the stack trace printed on console?